# how can I point to the start of a function in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am writing a program for my class that in a VERY simplified way simulates the way an operating system would handle an interrupt.

In C, I have an array `INTERRUPT_TABLE[]` that I have declared with:

```
typedef void (*FN_TYPE)();

extern FN_TYPE INTERRUPT_TABLE[];
```

I want to set it so that each position in the array points to the beginning of a different function that is contained elsewhere in my program - for example, `INTERRUPT_TABLE[0]` should point to the beginning of the function `handle_trap()`.

I thought that I could simply say: `INTERRUPT_TABLE[0] = handle_trap;`  but that is not working. I get a compiler error that says "kernel.c:134: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

edit: figured out! I had my INTERRUPT_TABLE above the functions I was attempting to call, so they were being automatically declared as ints

Comment: What do you mean by "that is not working" ? What is the problem exactly ? Compile error ? Link error ? Run-time error ?

Comment: Be more specific; there are a lot of ways this could not work.  Syntax error?  Runtime error?

Comment: I am not sure but I would try `INTERRUPT_TABLE[0] = &handle_trap;`.

Comment: oh, sorry! Specifically, I get an error when I compile that states "kernel.c:134: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer"

Comment: where do you define the size of the array INTERRUPT_TABLE? As your definition only contains the line INTERRUPT_TABLE[], somewhere you must define it's size to allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 4):

Define "not working". That should work. I suspect we're missing some context. Are you tryingto initialize INTERRUPT_TABLE by saying `INTERRUPT_TABLE[0] = handle_trap;` somewhere at the top level? That particular syntax won't work there, but will work in a function body. Alternatively you can use initializer syntax:

```
  FN_TYPE INTERRUPT_TABLE[] = { handle_trap, ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Logan's answer:

**Only (function and object) declarations can appear in the "external" or file context.**

While `FN_TYPE INTERRUPT_TABLE[] = { handle_trap, ... };` is a definition with initialization, the following has one definition and one assignment operation:

```
FN_TYPE INTERRUPT_TABLE[];
INTERRUPT_TABLE[0] = handle_trap;
```

This assignment can't appear at the top level and is interpreted as a redefinition of `INTERRUPT_TABLE`.

However, this doesn't match up with the error message you got back.  For what it's worth, this simple program compiles successfully:

```
typedef void (*FN_TYPE) ();

extern FN_TYPE INTERRUPT_TABLE[];

void handle_trap() {
}

int main() {
    INTERRUPT_TABLE[0] = handle_trap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say elsewhere, I assume it is not in the same file. So you either need a header file that declares handler_trap() or you must declare it manually in your C file before using it:

```
extern void handler_trap();
```

Otherwise the compiler has no idea that handler_trap() is a function, which value it returns or which parameters it expects.